# Sudden access denied message

Tags: mysql

I have just found that my site is displaying an 'access denied' message on all urls!
I cannot access the cp either.
I can access the files via ftp but the config file gives me an error message:
Permission denied 
Error -160: could not start data transfer. This error message is also occuring on various other .php files in the system.

I tried disabling the htacess file but this made no difference.
A plain html file outputs ok.

I can access the datatbase via phpmyadmin.

Any suggestions how I can troubleshoot this issue or what might be causing it?

Comment: I'd hit up your host as it sounds more like a system issue rather then an EE issue if php files aren't rendering.

Comment: Definitely contact your ISP, this sounds like something was changed at the server level and it not being related to EE. It's possible that all the file permissions were borked somehow, especially if you're getting an FTP open permission denied error as well. I just not certain why PHPMyAdmin would still work or was that provided by the ISP? If so, it's possible it already had different ownership permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments.
My ISP sent an email saying an ftp account had been hacked and files changed.
Dont really think this was the case as one file was not accessible via that ftp account!
However I did find that most of the file permissions were changed so the files were not readable!
Once these permissions were fixed it is all working again correctly!

Comment: Great! You should accept your own answer to indicate the issue has been resolved. But yes, remember in these situations, even if its not the first thing you do, the ISP should be contacted, so they can tell you if something happened at the server level.